# Can I pass parameters to a Clicked event in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am adding some pins to a map, and when the user tap on this pin (actually the content of the pin) I want to open a specific page.

I want to do something like this:

```
async void OnPinClicked(Places place)
{
  await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyPage(place));
}

private void PopulateMap(List<Places> places)
{
  for (int index = 0; index < places.Count; index++)
  {
    var pin = new Pin
    {
      Type = PinType.Place,
      Position = new Position(places[index].Lat, places[index].Lon),
      Label = places[index].Name,
      Address = places[index].Address
    };

    pin.Clicked += (sender, ea) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Name: {0}", places[index].Name); // The app is crashing here (if I tap on a pin)
        OnPinClicked(places[index]);
    };

    MyMap.Pins.Add(pin);
  }
}
```

But I don't know if it is possible to pass parameters to the `OnPinClicked` function. Is that possible? If it is not, what can I do to solve this?

**Note**: I'm newbie on Xamarin and C#.

Comment: There is closure, see my answer AFTER QUESTION EDIT section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass arguments to event handlers.

You can write wrapper(decorator) for `Pin` class:

```
public class PinDecorator
{
    public int Index {get; set;}
    public Pin Pin {get; set;}
}
```

Then use this class in `PopulateMap()` method:

```
private void PopulateMap(List<Places> places)
{
  for (int index = 0; index < places.Count; index++)
  {
    var pinDecorator = new PinDecorator
    {
      Pin = new Pin
      {
        Type = PinType.Place,
        Position = new Position(places[index].Lat, places[index].Lon),
        Label = places[index].Name,
        Address = places[index].Address
      },
      Index = index
    };

    pinDecorator.Pin.Clicked += OnPinClicked;

    MyMap.Pins.Add(pinDecorator.Pin);
  }
}
```

And your click handler:

```
async void OnPinClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pinDecorator = sender as PinDecorator;

    if (pinDecorator != null)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyPage(pinDecorator.Index));
    }
}
```

**OR**

You can assign handler by another way:

```
var newIndex = index; // for avoiding closure
pin.Clicked += async (s, e) =>
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyPage(places[newIndex]));
};
```

**AFTER QUESTION EDIT:**

There is a closure. You should create new variable and use it inside handler.

```
var newIndex = index;
pin.Clicked += (sender, ea) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Name: {0}", places[newIndex].Name); 
    OnPinClicked(places[newIndex]);
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Roma. Using the `newIndex` worked like a charm.

Comment: @KelvinSalton, you are welcone

Answer (score 20):

**BindingContext**

```
<Button Text="Button1" Clicked="Button1_Clicked" BindingContext="333"/>

string data = ((Button)sender).BindingContext as string;

// data  = 333;
```

Comment: when I use the BindingContext, the color of my text inside button becomes transparent. Why is this happening?

Comment: thank you, interesting way to accomplish the task

Answer (score 1):

Just give a commandParameter from xaml.

Answer (score 0):

You can create it directly using a short coding version of `EventHandler`, which on your case is the same thing as calling `OnPinClicked`:

```
pin.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyPage(places[index]));
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Zroq. I'm receiving the following error message when trying to do that: `The 'await' operator can only be used when its containing lambda expression is marked with the 'async' modifier`.

Comment: Thanks. Now it compile, but if I tap on a pin the app crashes with the following error message: `Index was out of the range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index`

Comment: Replace your `pin.Clicked` lines with the above code. You are currently calling `OnPinClicked` twice.